# Getting duplicated sql result

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, node.js

I have 3 tables: Users, Articles and Votes

```
| Users |    | Articles |    |   Votes   |
|   id  |    |    id    |    |  userId   |
|  name |    |  title   |    | articleId |
| email |    |  userId  |    |    type   |
```

I want to get users list with Count voteup and Count votedown for each one.

I'm testing this query:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes as v WHERE v.type=1 AND v.articleId IN 
   (SELECT a.id From articles as a WHERE a.userId = u.id) ) AS totalvoteup,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes as v WHERE v.type=0 AND v.articleId IN 
   (SELECT a.id From articles as a WHERE a.userId = u.id) ) AS totalvotedown
FROM users as u
```

I have the list I want when I test it via phpmyadmin(the results number matches with the number of users in the table), but when I try to get through Node server(from AngularJs or Postman) I'm getting duplicate results:

```
{
"users": [
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Lennon",
    "email": "johnlennon@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Lennon 2",
    "email": "johnlennon2@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "John Lennon 3",
    "email": "johnlennon3@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "John Lennon 4",
    "email": "johnlennon4@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  }
],
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Lennon 1",
    "email": "johnlennon1@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Lennon 2",
    "email": "johnlennon2@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "John Lennon 3",
    "email": "johnlennon3@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "John Lennon 4",
    "email": "johnlennon4@gmail.com",
    "totalvoteup": 0,
    "totalvotedown": 0
  }
]
]
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Please update your question by a) showing a minimal set of sample data for your tables, and b) showing the actual output which you would get in MySQL, rather than JSON output which is hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

Am not a Java guy and am not sure about the problem in question, but the query can be written in better way

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.id,
       u.name,
       u.email,
       coalesce(totalvoteup,0) as totalvoteup,
       coalesce(totalvotedown,0) as totalvotedown
FROM   users AS u
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id,userId FROM articles) a
              ON a.userId = u.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(CASE WHEN v.type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS totalvoteup,
                         Count(CASE WHEN v.type = 0 THEN 1 END) AS totalvotedown,
                         v.articleId
                  FROM   votes v
                  GROUP  BY v.articleId) v
              ON a.id = v.articleId
```

May not help you to solve the problem just thought of sharing since I like query optimization

Comment: The user Id key in the vote table refers to the user who voted, not the article owner. So your query gives me the total vote that each user made, not ones they have received

Comment: @AmadouBeye - check now

Comment: It gives me duplicate results but I solve it by adding DISCTINCT next to the first SELECT. However totalvoteup and totalvotedown is setting to NULL when user have no article. How to get 0 instead ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye - use `COALESCE`.. Updated

Comment: Got it ! Your query is faster than mine ! Thank You
But I'm still getting duplicated result :(

Comment: @AmadouBeye - Are you getting duplicates records in the above query result. If yes, then add sample data of all three tables and expected result

Comment: I just saw that node server executes this query twice and I don't know why